# Can't catch select2-* events using select2 combo

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-events

I must be missing something, because I'm trying to catch `select2` events but can't seem to make it.

**HTML:**

```
<body id="body">
  <input type='text' />
  <br />
  <input type='text' id='e11' />
  <br />
  <input type='text' />
  <br />
  <div id='out' />
</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#e11").select2({
  placeholder: 'select and item',
  data: [{id: 0, text: 'story'},{id: 1, text: 'bug'},{id: 2, text: 'task'}]
});

$("#e11")
  .on("select2-focus", function(e) { log("select2-focus");})
  .on("select2-blur",  function(e) { log("select2-blur");})
  .on("change",        function(e) { log("change");})
  .on('focus',         function(e) { log('focus');
});
```

The only event I catch is the change event.

What am I missing?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opensas/JQazb/) showing it in action.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there's an incompatibility with select2 3.3.2 and jQuery 1.9.1

upgrading to select2 3.4.0 (the latest version) solved the problem

unfortunately, select2-3.4.0 is not yet available on any cdn (so I can update the fiddle)

Comment: These events weren't firing for me either. I was also using select2 3.3.2, but with jQuery 1.8.2, so I don't know if it's a compatibility problem between the two, or just a bug in that version of select2. Either way, upgrading to select2 3.4.2 fixed the issue. Thanks for posting this as it saved me time.

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful

Answer (score 0):

Select2.js is meant to replace `<select>` elements with `<option>`s. Not for `<input>` afaik.